# Javascript validation is not working in aspx page for allvalidate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Allvalidate() {
            var ValidationSummary = "";
            ValidationSummary += NameValidation;
            ValidationSummary += EmailValidation;
            ValidationSummary += MobilenumValidation;
            if (ValidationSummary != "") {
                alert("ValidationSummary");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert("Information Submitted Successfuly");
                return true;
            }
            }
            function NameValidation() {

                var userid;
                var controlid = document.getElementById("<%=Textusername.ClientID%>");
                userid = controlid.value;
                var val = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
                if (userid == "") {
                    alert ("Enter your name" + "\n");
                }
                if (val.test(userid))
                {
                    return "";
                }
                else{
                    alert("Name accepts only spaces and character" + "\n");
                }
        }
        function EmailValidation() {
            var userid;
            var controlid = document.getElementById("<%=Textemail.ClientID%>");
            userid = controlid;
            var val = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            if (userid == "") {
                alert("Enter your name" + "\n");
            }
            if (val.test(userid)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                alert("Email should be like this example xyz@abc.com");
            }
        }
        function MobilenumValidation()
        {
        var userid;
            var controlid = document.getElementById("<%=Textmobilenum.ClientID%>");
            userid = controlid;
            var val = /^[\d\.\-]+$/;
             if (userid == "") {
                 alert("Enter your Mobile Number" + "\n");
            }
            if (val.test(userid)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                alert("PhoneNumber should be only in digits ");
            }
        }
        </script>
```

aspx:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnsub" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
OnClick="btnsub_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:Allvalidate()" />
```

The above code is not working, if i enter invalid mobile number,name and email it will accepted.

May i know, what is my mistake?

Thanks,

Comment: You are alerting not returning any validation message in your functions...

Comment: If i use return all the fields are empty.. so again i need to enter value from first..

Comment: But when you are checking if (ValidationSummary != ""), it will always be "" as because you are not returning if the validation is failing

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @CodingDefined Actually i m new to .net,.. i just confused with javascript.. can you please elaborate your comment? Thanks

Comment: You need to have return values, not only for sucess outcomes.

Comment: I need if i enter invalid name.. it need to shows "enter valid name" in alert.

Comment: Your function works fine, just have a look at http://codepen.io/codingdefined/pen/vLOpRv

Comment: @CodingDefined: what about for email and mobile number validation?

Comment: For Email and Number you should use   `userid = controlid.value;` not   `userid = controlid;` Check Updated http://codepen.io/codingdefined/pen/vLOpRv

Comment: @CodingDefined: i don't need success message. i already set, if i submit all valid value, then it will displayed in gridview.. so no need success message.. thanks

Comment: @CodingDefined: and your code in codepen.. shows lots of alerts. I need if i enter invalid means, it shows "invalid" else enter your name" .. thats it.. can you help me? thanks

Comment: @Rani done...http://codepen.io/codingdefined/pen/vLOpRv

Comment: @Coding: thanks for your valuable time.. but i didnt get properly.. if i enter submit button directly without enter any inout value, it shows all the alerts repeatedly..